# how to select partial dataframe by datetimeindex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex, pandas-loc

I have a Dataframe with a datetimeindex and a datetimeindex and i need to select only the rows from the datetimeindex. how to do?

```
ix = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-07-18 00:00:00', '2019-07-18 00:01:00', '2019-07-18 00:02:00', '2019-07-18 00:03:00', '2019-07-18 00:04:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Time', freq=None)

df_ix = ['2019-07-19 00:01:00','2019-07-19 00:02:00','2019-07-19 00:03:00','2019-07-19 00:04:00', '2019-07-19 00:05:00']
df = pd.DataFrame({"col:[np.nan]* len(df_ix)}, index = df_ix)
```

how can i do that?
is there a better way than `df[df.index.isin(ix)]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `loc`

```
out = df.loc[ix]
```

Comment: forgot to mention:I get a deprecation error when doing this. (passing list likes to .loc is no longer allowed) Python3.8